# How Do I Acquire Androids ACCELEROMETER data using sqlite?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am currently creating an android application where I am using an Accelerometer to record movement. I wanted to know how do I record this data onto a database? Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html#databasetutorial) that walks you through creating and using a sqlite database on android.

It should be easy to adapt it to persist your telemetry.